# sailsjs sockets and nginx proxy

Tags: node.js, nginx, sails.js, sails.io.js

i have a nodejs sails app proxied by nginx.Everything works fine but cant seem to connect to sails.io websocket.I get the error below in browser

```
Refused to connect to 'wss://youtmail.tk/socket.io/?__sails_io_sdk_version=1.2.1&__sails_io_sdk_platform=browser&__sails_io_sdk_language=javascript&EIO=3&transport=websocket' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src https: data: 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'". Note that 'connect-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.
```

and here is my nginx conf

```
server {
    server_name youtmail.tk;

     location /{
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:1338;
 listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/youtmail.tk-0001/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/youtmail.tk-0001/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot


}

server {
    if ($host = youtmail.tk) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot
}listen 80;
    server_name youtmail.tk;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot


}
```

any help on how to solve this??